# Build error while using Armadillo on Windows platform

Tags: c++, templates, armadillo

I had installed armadillo library on window visual studio 2013. When i attempted to build the solution. The following build error occurred. Any help will be appreciated.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\users\haixun\desktop\test_programs\testingapplication\armadillo-5.100.2\include\armadillo_bits/diskio_meat.hpp(787): error C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
1>          c:\users\haixun\desktop\test_programs\testingapplication\armadillo-5.100.2\include\armadillo_bits/diskio_meat.hpp(1626) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool arma::diskio::convert_naninf<eT>(eT &,const std::string &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              eT=arma::u32
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\haixun\desktop\test_programs\testingapplication\armadillo-5.100.2\include\armadillo_bits/diskio_meat.hpp(1652) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool arma::diskio::load_arma_ascii<arma::u32>(arma::Mat<arma::u32> &,std::istream &,std::string &)' being compiled
1>          c:\users\haixun\desktop\test_programs\testingapplication\armadillo-5.100.2\include\armadillo_bits/diskio_meat.hpp(1571) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool arma::diskio::load_arma_ascii<double>(arma::Mat<double> &,std::istream &,std::string &)' being compiled
1>          c:\users\haixun\desktop\test_programs\testingapplication\armadillo-5.100.2\include\armadillo_bits/Mat_meat.hpp(6553) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool arma::diskio::load_arma_ascii<double>(arma::Mat<double> &,const std::string &,std::string &)' being compiled
1>          c:\users\haixun\desktop\test_programs\testingapplication\armadillo-5.100.2\include\armadillo_bits/Mat_meat.hpp(6536) : while compiling class template member function 'bool arma::Mat<double>::load(const std::string,const arma::file_type,const bool)'
1>          Source.cpp(50) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool arma::Mat<double>::load(const std::string,const arma::file_type,const bool)' being compiled
1>          c:\users\haixun\desktop\test_programs\testingapplication\armadillo-5.100.2\include\armadillo_bits/typedef_mat_fixed.hpp(41) : see reference to class template instantiation 'arma::Mat<double>' being compiled
1>c:\users\haixun\desktop\test_programs\testingapplication\armadillo-5.100.2\include\armadillo_bits/diskio_meat.hpp(794): error C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in Visual Studio.  Try the updated version of Armadillo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that someone downvoted your question; it seems reasonable to me.

These are warnings, which in this particular case are harmless. You must have the option turned on to treat warnings as errors. Your options seem to be:

1. Turn off the option to treat warnings as errors.
2. Turn off that particular warning (project wide).
3. Turn off that particular warning whenever you `#include <armadillo>`.

Option 3 is probably best, especially if the warnings as errors option is company policy. Make sure to push and pop the warning options; see [this MSDN page on warning pragmas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx). You could put the whole lot (pragmas and include) into a little header file, which is probably a good idea anyway since Visual Studio won't autocomplete `#include <armadillo>` (since it doesn't have a file extension).